# Insert_batch error - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following array for insert into database using Codeigniter's insert_batch.

```
 Array
(
[td_customer_lphone] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [cust_lphone_id] => 
                [l_ph_cc] => +98
                [l_ph_ac] => 777
                [l_ph_no] => 77
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [cust_lphone_id] => 
                [l_ph_cc] => +78
                [l_ph_ac] => 66
                [l_ph_no] => 66
            )

    )
```

It gives the following error while insert.

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `td_customer_lphone` (`0`, `1`) VALUES ('',''), ('+98','+78'), ('777','66'), ('77','66')
```

What am I doing wrong

Thanks for any help..

Comment: the associative arrays's key is `0` which literally translates as column names into the table, which is the cause of the error

Comment: `$this->db->insert_batch('mytablename',$data['td_customer_lphone']);`

Answer (score 1):

The (0, 1) in your statement is supposed to be a list of the field names that you  are inserting into - you can't use ordinal field numbers as far as I am aware

something more like (replace field1 and field2 with the names ofg the columns from your table

```
INSERT INTO td_customer_lphone (field1, field2) VALUES ('',''), ('+98','+78'), ('777','66'), ('77','66')
```